# How to detect in ARKit if real world object fits into 3d object (Box)?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit

How to detect in ARKit if real world object fits into 3d object (Box). For example I have a real shoe on the floor and I want to check if it will fit in the shoebox (virtually created shoe box) or not. How we can check this?

Answer (score 0):

You might generate a number of boxes presets and make the user put his content inside of it to check if it fits. Here is a visual reference of that feature [made in the Easyjet app](https://www.businesstraveller.com/business-travel/2019/02/07/easyjet-adds-ar-bag-scanning-feature-to-iphone-app/). [image]

Comment: Thanks Ivan, something similar I already created but i want to notify user if the real world object collides with the cage or is bigger than the cage. How we can detect the collision ?